# Can't open file from internal storage. Code crashing in Android 7.1

Tags: android, performance, android-sdcard, android-internal-storage

Following code works perfectly for Android 5, 6. But its crashing on Android 7.1

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(""));
        intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///" + "sdcard/path/"+fName), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent1);
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.amey.newunipunebuddy, PID: 19574
              android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///sdcard/unipunebuddy_data/timetables/Timetable.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
                  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9022)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8983)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1519)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                  at com.amey.newunipunebuddy.Timetable$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(Timetable.java:498)
                  at com.amey.newunipunebuddy.Timetable$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(Timetable.java:415)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
Application terminated.

Comment: There is no path named `/sdcard` on most Android devices. This is why developers should **never hardcode paths**. Beyond that, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your app.

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: Please see updated question. I've added logcat.

Comment: Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 6.0 onwards you need to prompt user for permission to write to external storage (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html (am assuming, despite title, that it is writing to external storage given use of /sdcard ?)

Comment: I've requested permission.

Comment: Some phones such as the Nexus series use /sdcard as the internal storage for user data. It is still interpreted by the OS as an External storage device. OP might have misunderstood between them.

Answer (score 0):

[Google documentation on external storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

You have to use `getExternalFilesDir()`. Take a look at the link for other options (pictures, music,...)

Also check your permissions, I don't remember when but now Android asks you to validate permissions at app startup. Maybe it is linked to the different systems. (5, 6,...)

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileUriExposedException
```

You expose the uri of your file to the outside world. Which Nougat does not allow you to do any more.

Use a file provider or file content provider to serve the file.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm able to save the files perfectly. But can't open.

Comment: You can open them too. Your app can. But you cannot transfer the file path, using an intent, to another app. You have to use a file provider to serve the file.